# Join separator ignored

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to create an array in PowerShell and then join it to a single string. This is my code:

```
$solutionRoot = "c:\temp"
$libraryPaths = @(
    $solutionRoot + "\a",
    $solutionRoot + "\b"
)

$joined = ($libraryPaths -join ",")
$joined

$joined2 = [string]::Join(",", $libraryPaths)
$joined2
```

However, the output is:

```
c:\temp\a c:\temp\b
c:\temp\a c:\temp\b
```

and there is no separator between my paths (the desired output is `c:\temp\a,c:\temp\b`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't really getting an array in `$libraryPaths` to start with.
Try this:

```
$solutionRoot = "c:\temp"
$libraryPaths = @(
    ($solutionRoot + "\a"),
    ($solutionRoot + "\b")
)

$joined = ($libraryPaths -join ",")
$joined

$joined2 = [string]::Join(",", $libraryPaths)
$joined2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize comma operator has such a high operator precedence. If you could add that explanation to your answer, it would make it even better.

Answer (score 3):

or just:

```
$libraryPaths = @(
    "$solutionRoot\a",
    "$solutionRoot\b"
)
```